# Online UPS with external batteries connected to separate charger. Is it safe?

Tags: power-electronics

Our company needs to keep a few devices powered in case of blackout as long as 8 hours and diesel generator is not an option. So, we are thinking about installing a 2KVA online UPS and connect 48V 200Ah battery. That will satisfy our basic needs, but the 6A charger in UPS will take very long time to charge the battery. Having another high-current charger looks better, but I am unsure about how it will interfere with UPS charger.

So, my first question is: What will happen if I connect another charger to battery which is also connected to online UPS? Is it safe or will the two chargers interfere and cause damage to electronics/battery?

And second question: If the above method won't work, what if I put a diode between UPS and batteries so that the diode will block charging current from UPS? Will it have any unwanted side effect?

Comment: `will XYZ happen?` is not an answerable question because it asks for 100% certainty ... `could XYZ happen?` is a reasonable, answerable question

Comment: it's safe, but could mess with the smarts of the UPS and make it complain, refuse to charge, or even refuse to work, but it won't blow up or anything; the batteries themselves also spit out voltage, just like chargers, so each part can't really tell where the voltage is coming from, but it's possible the UPS might track/estimate SoC and get worried that the battery is defective or something.